# Text box on change ,ajax function to be called ...not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am using php and postgres database. I want a table value to be filled on entering of certain value in a text box(After doing certain calculations)..I tried to use onchange event and then calling ajax function but its not working.. i am using two ajx functions ..will that work??

Ajax Function:

```
function getAmount(order_quant,item) 
{    
   var strURL = "calc_amt.php?order=" + order_quant + "&item=" + item;
   var req = getXMLHTTP(); 

   if (req) 
   { 
      req.onreadystatechange = function() 
      { 
         if (req.readyState == 4) 
         { 
            // only if "OK" 
            if (req.status == 200) 
            { 
               document.getElementById('amt').innerHTML = req.responseText;  
            } 
            else 
            { 
               alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText); 
            } 
         }   
      }  

      req.open("GET", strURL, true); 
      req.send(null); 
   }     
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $articles['item_name']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $tot."(".$articles['description'].")";?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $articles['qty_in_stock'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $articles['min_reorder_qty'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="ordered_quant" id="order_quant" onChange="getAmount(this.id,$value)" required/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="amt"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $order_date; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ajax Function: function getAmount(order_quant,item) {  
  
  var strURL="calc_amt.php?order="+order_quant+"&item="+item;
  var req = getXMLHTTP();
  
  if (req) {
   
   req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
     // only if "OK"
     if (req.status == 200) {      
      document.getElementById('amt').innerHTML=req.responseText;      
     } else {
      alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
     }
    }    
   }   
   req.open("GET", strURL, true);
   req.send(null);
  }  
 }

Comment: Html Code:  <tr><td><?php echo $articles['item_name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $tot."(".$articles['description'].")";?></td>
                <td><?php echo $articles['qty_in_stock'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $articles['min_reorder_qty'];?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ordered_quant" id="order_quant" onChange="getAmount(this.id,$value)" required/></td>
                <td><div id="amt"></div></td>
                <td><?php echo $order_date; ?> </td>
            </tr>

Comment: Put code in question in proper format

Comment: This is my ajax function which gets called:

Comment: function getAmount(order_quant,item) {  
  
  var strURL="calc_amt.php?order="+order_quant+"&item="+item;
  var req = getXMLHTTP();
  
  if (req) {
   
   req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
     // only if "OK"
     if (req.status == 200) {      
      document.getElementById('amt').innerHTML=req.responseText;      
     } else {
      alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
     }
    }    
   }   
   req.open("GET", strURL, true);
   req.send(null);
  }  
 }

Comment: function getAmount(order_quant,item)   
  {
  var strURL="calc_amt.php?order="+order_quant+"&item="+item;
  var req = getXMLHTTP();
  
  if (req) {
   
   req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
     // only if "OK"
     if (req.status == 200) {      
      document.getElementById('amt').innerHTML=req.responseText;      
     } else {
      alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
     }
    }    
   }   
   req.open("GET", strURL, true);
   req.send(null);
  }  
 }

Comment: I want to call this function when user inputs value in text box

Comment: Always put all of your code with question in proper format edit your Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is on the second parameter. you are mixing PHP and Javascript there.
make sure you (php) tag your code

```
onChange="getAmount(this.id,<?php echo $value; ?>)"
```

I'm assuming $value is a php variable there...

Comment: Thanks!!! It called the function but its not giving the value that is entered in textbox

Comment: One is glad to be at service ;)